# Kubernetes Cluster - How to automatically generate documentation/Architecture of services

Tags: kubernetes

We started using Kubernetes, a few time ago, and now we have deployed a fair amount of services. It's becoming more and more difficult to know exactly what is deployed. I suppose many people are facing the same issue, so is there already a solution to handle this issue?
I'm talking of a solution that when connected to kubernetes (via kubectl for example) can generate a kind of map off the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

1. In order to display one or many resources you need to use `kubectl get` [command](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#get).
2. To show details of a specific resource or group of resources you can use `kubectl describe` [command](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#describe).

Please check the links I provided for more details and examples.

3. You may also want to use [Web UI (Dashboard)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/)

> Dashboard is a web-based Kubernetes user interface. You can use
>   Dashboard to deploy containerized applications to a Kubernetes
>   cluster, troubleshoot your containerized application, and manage the
>   cluster resources. You can use Dashboard to get an overview of
>   applications running on your cluster, as well as for creating or
>   modifying individual Kubernetes resources (such as Deployments, Jobs,
>   DaemonSets, etc). For example, you can scale a Deployment, initiate a
>   rolling update, restart a pod or deploy new applications using a
>   deploy wizard.

Let me know if that helped.

Comment: Thank you @OhHiMark, we are already using the Kubernetes dasboard. What i'm asking is this: Say for example you want to explain to someone the architecture of an app that's deployed on Kubernetes, he does not have to connect to your dashboard. I'm talking of a solution that when connected to kubernetes (via kubectl for example) can generate a kind of map off the cluster.

Comment: If you want to see a bigger picture I strongly recommend dashboards. 
If you need to go into more technical details you need `kubectl' commands listed above and play around with them to get the info you need.
Your question is very broad and without more detailed knowledge of your cluster and apps it is impossible to tell you how to explain that. However could you please tell why some one can have access to your cluster but not to the dashboards as your last sentence suggests?